# Section styling similar to the elsarticle class

Tags: fonts, sectioning, sections-paragraphs, elsarticle

Since I have become quite used to the [style of Elsevier articles](https://www.elsevier.com/authors/author-schemas/latex-instructions), I would like to adopt a similar style also for notes that are not intended for submission. In particular, I attempted to mimic the font selection as well as the paragraph and section styling. I did, however, find it difficult to extract the relevant declarations from the `elsarticle.cls`. Therefore I was hoping for a more trained eye to read them out, or point me to a similar template. Here's a direct link to the [class file](http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~garg/dist/garg/elsarticle.cls).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Look for `\@startsection` in the class file. You'll find the relevant styling for each sectioning command. `\@startsection` is a LaTeX internal, so you can just copy that definition to your document and it'll work.

Comment: Thanks, that looks very promising! Do you know where to look for the fonts?

Comment: You have to ping @PhelypeOleinik like I just did to get a prompt about your message. Welcome from me too. Also: usually in latex the font is chosen by using a package... If this is commented inside the documentclass code, you can check the output pdf from its properties and then just search "latex <font name>" to find the appropriate package except if you are willing to use XeLaTeX (where the method of using a specific font is easier if this is available on your operating system)

Comment: @q49168 `elsarticle` uses Computer Modern by default, unless you pass the `times` option, in which case it uses a close of Times New Roman. Computer Modern is the default in LaTeX, so you don't need to do anything. If you use the `times` option then `\usepackage{newtxtext}` and `\usepackage{newtxmath}` (`elsarticle` actually uses another package, which is a deprecated version of the ones I mentioned).

Comment: @koleygr Somehow I received a notification of OP's comment. I _think_ that after I leave a comment I “subscribe” to other comments on that post. Thanks anyhow :-)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: Oh... I was not sure about that... Are you sure you didn't received the notification after I pinged you? I think that I pinged you and then you received the notification... But may be if you are the only or the first one that commented you also get a notification... (Your thought seems like facebook stuff to me :P )

Comment: @koleygr Yes, I received the notification before because while I was writing my next comment yours popped up. But I don't know about facebook (nor do I know about notifications here), I just said what I saw :P

Comment: @koleygr Just so that you know, your last comment didn't send a notification. Don't ask me ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so thanks to [Phelype Oleinik](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/134574) the snippet below styles sections the way that the `elsarticle` class does.

```latex
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
           {18\p@ \@plus 6\p@ \@minus 3\p@}%
           {9\p@ \@plus 6\p@ \@minus 3\p@}%
           {\normalsize\bfseries\boldmath}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
           {12\p@ \@plus 6\p@ \@minus 3\p@}%
           {3\p@ \@plus 6\p@ \@minus 3\p@}%
           {\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}}
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
           {12\p@ \@plus 6\p@ \@minus 3\p@}%
           {\p@}%
           {\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}}
\makeatother
```

Headings of environments from the `amsthm` package are changed to small caps. For example:

```latex
\newtheorem{theorem}{\normalfont\scshape Theorem}
```

Also, as mentioned in the comments, Elsevier simply uses the default font (Computer Modern) unless one passes the `times` option, in which case the font resembles Times New Roman.

Comment: (+1) for the answer but I didn't mentioned anything about Elsevier fonts, @Phelipe did... I just told about a general approach of finding a font of any template...

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks anyway!